# Issue using Box2D and video in the same Processing sketch

Tags: processing, box2d

I trying to create a sketch with both the Box2D for Processing and Video libraries.
I have some boxes moving around and colliding with each other, and I want to texture these boxes with some video.
However, I get a long error message as soon as I put in the line of code to tell processing which video file I want to use.

```
import processing.video.*;
import shiffman.box2d.*;
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.*;
import org.jbox2d.common.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.*;


Box2DProcessing box2d;

int no_boxes = 7;

//All of our boxes
Box[] boxes = new Box[no_boxes];

//Boundry sides
Boundry[] boundry = new Boundry[4];

float angle = -PI/2;
float grav_rad = 30;

float boundr = 260;
float boundw = 30;

PVector direction = new PVector();

Movie mouth;


void setup() {
  size(800,800,P3D);
  frameRate(60);
  colorMode(HSB,360,100,100);
  noStroke();

  //Load the movie
  mouth = new Movie(this,"mouth1.mov");
  mouth.play();

  // Initialize box2d physics and create the world
  box2d = new Box2DProcessing(this);
  box2d.createWorld();

  //Create the boxes
  for (int n=0;n<no_boxes; n++) {
    boxes[n] = new Box(random(200,600), random (200,600));
  }

  //Create the boundries
  boundry[0] = new Boundry(400+boundr,400,boundw,2*boundr+boundw);
  boundry[1] = new Boundry(400-boundr,400,boundw,2*boundr+boundw);
  boundry[2] = new Boundry(400,400+boundr,2*boundr+boundw, boundw);
  boundry[3] = new Boundry(400,400-boundr,2*boundr+boundw, boundw);



}

void movieEvent (Movie m) {
  m.read();
}


void draw() {

  background(200,50,80);
  image(mouth,0,0);

  angle+= radians(0.3);

  direction.x = grav_rad*cos(angle);
  direction.y = grav_rad*sin(angle);

  box2d.setGravity(-direction.x, direction.y);

  camera(width/2.0, height/2.0, (height/2.0) / tan(PI*30.0 / 180.0), width/2.0, height/2.0, 0, 0-map(direction.x,-10,10,-1,1), 0-map(direction.y,-10,10,-1,1), 0);   //x, y, z -> need to change between x and y

  box2d.step();

  // Display all the boxes
  for (Box b: boxes) {
    b.display();
  }

  //display the boundries
  boundry[0].display();
  boundry[1].display();
  boundry[2].display();
  boundry[3].display();

}
```

Here is the error message I get:

finishLifecycleAction(com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$3): ++++++ timeout reached ++++++ main-FPSAWTAnimator#00-Timer0
finishLifecycleAction(com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$3): OK false- pollPeriod 6, blocking true -> res false, waited 1002/1000 - main-FPSAWTAnimator#00-Timer0
 - com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator[started true, animating true, paused false, drawable 1, totals[dt 0, frames 0, fps 0.0], modeBits 1, init'ed true, animThread Thread[main-FPSAWTAnimator#00-Timer0-FPSAWTAnimator#00-Timer1,5,main], exclCtxThread false(null)]
    [2]: com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.finishLifecycleAction(AnimatorBase.java:634)
    [3]: com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator.stop(FPSAnimator.java:326)
    [4]: processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL.stopThread(PSurfaceJOGL.java:722)
    [5]: processing.core.PApplet.dispose(PApplet.java:3830)
    [6]: processing.core.PApplet.die(PApplet.java:3741)
    [7]: processing.core.PApplet.die(PApplet.java:3751)
    [8]: processing.video.Movie.initGStreamer(Unknown Source)
    [9]: processing.video.Movie.(Unknown Source)
    [10]: Rotating_mouth_boxes_100620.setup(Rotating_mouth_boxes_100620.java:58)
    [11]: processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2432)
    [12]: processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$DrawListener.display(PSurfaceJOGL.java:866)
    [13]: jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:692)
    [14]: jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:674)
    [15]: jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:443)
    [16]: jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1293)
    [17]: jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
    [18]: com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:782)
    [19]: com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:81)
    [20]: com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:453)
    [21]: com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$MainTask.run(FPSAnimator.java:178)
    [22]: java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    [23]: java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Any ideas? I have successfully used both Box2D and video separately, but something about having them in the same sketch seems to be an issue.

Comment: What's your IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this one, but it looks like the `P3D`(OpenGL) renderer needs to finish initialisation within a timeframe and something is delaying so long that it times out.

There's a shot loading the movie could be a problem.

If you can get away with the default software renderer, try it:

```
size(800,800,JAVA2D);
```

and remove the `camera()`. Hopefully this visually is still ok.

I can't think of a clean solution at the moment.

The other workaround would be to initialise the movie later, after the `P3D` renderer is ready. You could for example use an extra boolean variable to keep track if the movie load has been triggered to ensure that happens only once.

Here's an (untested) example: hopefully the comments illustrate the workaround:

```
import processing.video.*;
import shiffman.box2d.*;
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.*;
import org.jbox2d.common.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.*;


Box2DProcessing box2d;

int no_boxes = 7;

//All of our boxes
Box[] boxes = new Box[no_boxes];

//Boundry sides
Boundry[] boundry = new Boundry[4];

float angle = -PI/2;
float grav_rad = 30;

float boundr = 260;
float boundw = 30;

PVector direction = new PVector();

Movie mouth;

// keep track if movie load was called
boolean wasMovieLoadCalled = false;

void setup() {
  size(800,800,P3D);
  frameRate(60);
  colorMode(HSB,360,100,100);
  noStroke();

  // Initialize box2d physics and create the world
  box2d = new Box2DProcessing(this);
  box2d.createWorld();

  //Create the boxes
  for (int n=0;n<no_boxes; n++) {
    boxes[n] = new Box(random(200,600), random (200,600));
  }

  //Create the boundries
  boundry[0] = new Boundry(400+boundr,400,boundw,2*boundr+boundw);
  boundry[1] = new Boundry(400-boundr,400,boundw,2*boundr+boundw);
  boundry[2] = new Boundry(400,400+boundr,2*boundr+boundw, boundw);
  boundry[3] = new Boundry(400,400-boundr,2*boundr+boundw, boundw);

}

void movieEvent (Movie m) {
  m.read();
}


void draw() {
  // if load wasn't called
  if(wasMovieLoadCalled == false){

    //Load the movie
    mouth = new Movie(this,"mouth1.mov");
    mouth.play();

    // update the variable so load happens only once
    wasMovieLoadCalled = true;

  }

  background(200,50,80);

  // ensure the movie is loaded before trying to display it
  if(mouth != null){
    image(mouth,0,0);
  }


  angle+= radians(0.3);

  direction.x = grav_rad*cos(angle);
  direction.y = grav_rad*sin(angle);

  box2d.setGravity(-direction.x, direction.y);

  camera(width/2.0, height/2.0, (height/2.0) / tan(PI*30.0 / 180.0), width/2.0, height/2.0, 0, 0-map(direction.x,-10,10,-1,1), 0-map(direction.y,-10,10,-1,1), 0);   //x, y, z -> need to change between x and y

  box2d.step();

  // Display all the boxes
  for (Box b: boxes) {
    b.display();
  }

  //display the boundries
  boundry[0].display();
  boundry[1].display();
  boundry[2].display();
  boundry[3].display();

}
```

Comment: Ayyyy thanks I got it sorted!  You were right about the 3D renderer, when I turned that off the long error message went away.
However I then got another error message - I forgot to put the movie file in a folder called "data" so the code didn't know where to find it (!). Which is why it was timing out, but with the 3D renderer in there as well it wasn't giving the standard error message.  
Anyway, once I put the movie in the right folder it now works with & without the 3D renderer.

Turned out to just be a silly mistake but thanks for your help!!